# Allow different divs to be moved by different IP Sessions

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I am a beginner in coding, forgive me for the question,

I have this fiddle **http://jsfiddle.net/G48vx/4/**

and I want the two boxes to be moved by two different persons who enter the website. Person A can only move the blue box, and Person B can only move the red box. How can I achieve that? I have heard about `websockets`, but I'm not sure which technologies I need for this. Does anyone have any demo + codes of similar multi sessions? THank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[www.firebase.com](http://www.firebase.com), should fit your requirements.  The framework uses web workers but wraps it all up nicely for you.  As long as your JavaScript is ok you shouldn't have too many issues with it.

Comment: hi. thanks for your answer. I checked firebase website they just have a tetris demo. can Firebase be used to implement other real time games?

Comment: Yes, it can.  I built a prototype for battleships last year with it.